# VB6 ADO error when adding WHERE clause in query

Tags: sql, csv, vb6, ado

I have a csv file with the following information:

```
NOMBRE,EDAD,FECHA
MARIO,30,24/12/2002
MARIA,90,24/12/2001
PEDRO,10,24/12/2004
```

Then I want to interact with it using ADO like this:

```
Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset

oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
& "Data Source=" & Environ("temp") & ";" _
& "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(;)"";Persist Security Info=False"

Set oRS = oConn.Execute("select * from datos.csv")
Dim ofield As ADODB.Field

Do Until oRS.EOF
    For Each ofield In oRS.Fields
        Debug.Print "Field Name = " & ofield.Name & " Field Value = " & ofield.Value
    Next ofield
    oRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

It works! Returns:

```
Field Name = NOMBRE Field Value = MARIO
Field Name = EDAD Field Value = 30
Field Name = FECHA Field Value = 24/12/2002
Field Name = NOMBRE Field Value = MARIA
Field Name = EDAD Field Value = 90
Field Name = FECHA Field Value = 24/12/2001
Field Name = NOMBRE Field Value = PEDRO
Field Name = EDAD Field Value = 10
Field Name = FECHA Field Value = 24/12/2004
```

But If I try to do a query like this:

```
SELECT EDAD FROM datos.csv WHERE NOMBRE='MARIO'
```

I have the following error:

```
-2147467259 (800040005) Error in 'Execute' method of '_Connection' object.
```

What am I dismissing? The only thing I've done is adding a 'where' clause in the query...

Comment: If I add `"WHERE NOMBRE='MARIO'"` to your existing code exactly as it is, it works for me, is that what your trying?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did. I've added `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 Library` reference.